# How To Close Unknown Window

Tags: wpf, vb.net

all,, I have a project that is built in VB.Net 2010 and WPF 4. I have an option to return to a sign-in screen, yet this option can only be accessed from a separate (quit confirmation) window. This function can be called when one of about a hundred windows are open behind the quit confirmation window.

What I want to do is close the quit confirmation window, and the other window that is open, but open the sign-in window. I know to use "Me.Close()" to close the quit confirmation window, and I know how to open the sign-in window, but I do not know how to close the other window that is open.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you give the constructor of the quit-confirmation-window a reference to the window it should close when that option is chosen?

Edit: Two examples of how to do it:
Often you'd like to open a confirmation-dialogue when the window is being closed, so you'd create it in the Closing event-handler like this:

```
    private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        ConfirmationDialog diag = new ConfirmationDialog();
        diag.ShowDialog();
        switch (diag.Result)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Here your window waits for the confirmation dialogue to return (`diag.Show` would not wait), if that is the case you do not need any information about the window in the dialogue itself. (`Result` is a custom property that you can define in your dialogue if the `DialogResult` bool is not differentiated enough)

If your dialogue is opened whenever and you cannot wait for it to return you can create it with a reference:

```
private void OpenConfirmDialog()
{
    ConfirmationDialog diag = new ConfirmationDialog(this);
    diag.Show()
}
```

and in your dialogue code:

```
public ConfirmationDialog(Window owner)
{
    Owner = owner;
}

public void OpenWelcomeScreenThing()
{
    this.Close();
    Owner.Close();
    new WelcomeScreen().Show();
}
```

or something like that. Alternatively you could work with events as well.